# Reusing jQuery UI CSS to create Widget Boxes Side-by-side

Tags: jquery, css

I'd like to recycle [jQuery UI css](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/) to create widgetboxes that are side by side and also multiple rows...

Ideal:

```
[] []
[] []
```

My try so far ends up getting all the UI widgetboxes coalesced on top of each other. Even using tables to try forcing the distinct cells.. Here is the unsuccessful code for each cell:

```
<div id="1" class="ui-widget ui-state-highlight ui-corner-all" style="padding:5px;margin:3px;width:173px;display:inline;height:130px;">
  <img src="sampleimgblock.png" width="173" height="130" />
</div>
```

Comment: I think you need to define more clearly what is a widgetbox. Is it like the jQuery UI Dialog box?

Comment: it's any jQuery element that looks like a box... could be ui-tabs or even the accordion. there's a clickable image inside the box.

Answer (score 0):

I guess I really don't understand what you are trying to accomplish.  If it's 4 components 2 X 2 you could do something like this.

CSS

```
.ui-widget{float: left}
.ui-widget:nth-child(3){clear:both} //Only works in modern browsers
```

jQuery fallback

```
$('.ui-widget:nth-child(3)).css('clear', 'both');
```

This will start a new "row" every 3rd component creating something similar to your diagram.